# MemoryStream: local or not?

Tags: c#

This is a really really simple question.

Does the C# `MemoryStream` hold the data on the client or on the server?

For example I have a form that when posted uploads a file to my s3 bucket, but before it does that it reads the file into the memory stream. If that file has to be uploaded to the server first and held in a `MemoryStream` on the server, then that is bad and I need to rethink my solution.

If the `MemoryStream` is local to the client, then that is good.

Comment: The memory behind a memory stream is wherever your C# code runs. So it's local, it can't even know there is a server.

Comment: Your C# is local. `MemoryStream` means its in memory. Given that there is no way to work out what your server is running... The C# can only alter the client. Therefore memory refers to LOCAL.

Comment: Or do you have some very confused assumptions about ASP.NET webforms? Here the client is javascript and the server C#? In that case the memory stream will be allocated on your server, not on amazon's server and not in the browser.

Comment: What server?  How would MemoryStream know about any other servers?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I will agree as long as you take remoting out of the equation ;p

Comment: LOL, but that's a *different* MemoryStream object ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, and your point? ;p http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx

Comment: @leppie So much blindness today...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MemoryStream holds the data in your system's memory (RAM). So it will be on whatever computer the code is running on.

In this case, it appears that you're saying your server-side code is using a MemoryStream to hold the data that comes in from a form POST. Typically it's better to save the file to a temporary location on the disk, rather than trying to hold the entire file in memory.

Or, if you're expecting to accept really large files, and you don't need to do any intermediate processing, you could just do a pass-through stream straight up to s3. The danger in this is that if the upload fails to complete, it'll probably take a little more effort to ensure things are cleaned up properly.

Comment: So when I post a file to my WebApi, when it loads it into the MemoryStream, that is the RAM on the server?